# Java application - How to display all the records from mysql database in netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I`m having trouble with showing all the records from my database... 
I got database 'library' and table 'books'. 
Structure of 'members' : id, title, description, author, publisher, yearPublished.

Here is my java code method:

```
public static void preuzmi() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, SQLException, IllegalAccessException{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/library", "root","");

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.executeQuery("select * from books");
ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();

while(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString("title"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("description"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("author"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("publisher"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("yearPublished"));

        }
```

when i run this method preuzmi(); in main class it shows me only titles from db... 
How can i show other records??? Please help me. THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing braces around your while-statement.

```
while(rs.next()) { // this tiny little '{' is reeeaaaally important here
            System.out.println(rs.getString("title"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("description"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("author"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("publisher"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("yearPublished"));
}
```

When you don't put braces after a while, if, for, etc. only the directly following statement will be executed. The rest will be executed after the entire loop is over.